# StackOverflowError, can't find where in my code I made the call

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

I have a StackOverflowError in Java and it doesn't tell me any line in my own code, the relevant part of the stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:523)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2838)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:439)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2838)
```

I've tried getting the stack trace from the throwable, but for some reason it doesn't contain the relevant nodes, I'm trying to find some inpoint in my code as to where the error is.  Also I've tried to reduce the stack size to 128k to get the error earlier, no avail.

Comment: Post the entire stack trace. You are not doing recursive calls?

Comment: Could you post your calling code?  Also, none of the stack trace you have provided is your code. (unless you work for Oracle...)  The stack trace from your code will be more helpful I believe.

Comment: I bet the exception you are looking for is being swallowed and a new one is then rethrown somewhere.

Comment: "doesn't tell me any line in my own code"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a `StackOverFlowError`, the stack trace is often truncated (since it is too long), which does not really help finding the error.

In your case, assuming the part you copied is the one which is repeating, it looks like you added a map to a collection, which in turn is a as a key or value of the original map, and then use the `toString()` method on one of these objects.

The default implementation of `toString()` for a map (in AbstractMap) then calls `StringBuilder.append(...)` with all its keys and values, which in turn will invoke `toString` on these. For AbstractCollection, the same is valid for the elements of the collection.

(The example in Jon's answer does a similar thing with two collections instead of a map and a collection.)

**Solutions:**

- Remove the cycles in your collection/map graph.
- If you need cycles in your collection/map-graph:

  - avoid calling `toString()` (and `hashCode`/`equals`, too), or
  - override the `toString()` method of one of them to break the cycle.

Comment: +1 - in Eclipse let it happen in Debug mode, and let the debugger stop on uncaught exceptions.  You can then inspect the StringBuffer being built and it should show up immediately.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example which will cause the same error, which may help:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list1.add(list2);
        list2.add(list1);
        String text = list1.toString();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Note that just using:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(list);
String text = list.toString();
```

... did *not* produce the error. It's smart enough to notice if the collection is *immediately* within itself - but not *nested* within itself.

Of course, you may not be using the same collection, so that may change what's going on - but hopefully this has given you a starting point.

Comment: Actually I have a lot of collections that and cycles, the mistake in the code must be to call toString somewhere.  Maybe a debug printout statement is actually causing a bug, but it still would be fun to know the line in my own code where it happens.

Comment: @Dude Dawg: You mean you *intend* to have a collection nested within itself? Ick. That sounds like a recipe for problems, to be honest... is there any way you could change the design to not require that sort of thing? I suspect this won't be the last time it bites you.

Comment: Oh shit!  I removed a debug print statement and that was it!  Thanks.

Comment: I'm implementing an LALR(1) parser, the algorithms that I'm implementing are expressed in terms of sets, and sometimes sets of sets of sets, a state needs to refer to another state that could indirectly refer back somehow, because there are usually loops in a grammar.  Thanks for the help though.  In case someone else finds this thread on Google I still wonder about the initial question, although my problem is solved, so thanks.